# Angular: Получить pattern применяющийся в данный момент

Tags: angularjs

Есть необходимость при изменении одного поля, заменять валидацию другого. Решил сделать набор паттернов для подстановки. Второе поле выглядит так:

```
<input ng-model="iname" ng-pattern="Pattern.{{(type?type:'Empty')}}" type="text" name="iname"/>
```

Объект паттернов:

```
    $scope.Pattern = {
        Empty: /[\s]/,
        value1: /^\d{6}$/,
        value2: /^[\d]$/,
    },
```

Т.е. при смене `type` подменяется `ng-pattern`. Сейчас валидация всегда падает, ругаясь на `pattern`.

Есть ли способ, из формы получить текущий паттерн по типу `FormName.inputName.$pattern`?

Comment: можете сделать краткий пример на Plunkr воспроизводящий проблему? сейчас не совсем понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать и на что ругается, возможно просто нужно использовать bracket notation: `Pattern[type||'Empty']` но возможно что вы спрашиваете что-то другое

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать что-то вроде этого [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/4e61pdcr/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.type = null;
  $scope.getPattern = function(type) {
    return $scope.Pattern[type] || $scope.Pattern.Empty;
  };
  $scope.Pattern = {
    Empty: /[\s]/,
    value1: /^\d{6}$/,
    value2: /^[\d]$/,
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="type">
  <input ng-model="iname" ng-pattern="getPattern(type)" type="text" name="iname" />

  <pre>type={{getPattern(type).toString()}}</pre>
</body>
```